# Make animation play using c# in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm having trouble with my animating as i have used "animator. set Bools" with my if statements to animate my player but there seems to be a lot of errors and so i have decided to try and make the c# script play a certain animation if a set rule happens within the code but i need someone to tell me what code i can use to make an animation play.

for e.g

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
        doublejump = true;

    }
    else
    {

        if (doublejump)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {

                moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
                doublejump = false;
                canjump = false;
                //code to play my double jump animation
            }
        }

    }
}
```

please help, by the way i'm a beginner at programming.

Comment: What does your animator controller look like? Did you set up transitions between the states?

Comment: i set up a lot of transitions and it works but not the way i want it to

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. I would recommend walking through one of the tutorials: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up an Animator on the gameobject that your script is on and you have created the different states in it, you just need to fetch the Animator and play the wanted animation/state:

```
Animator m_Animator;

void Start()
{
    //Fetch the Animator from your GameObject
    m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    //Press the space key to play the "Jump" state
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        m_Animator.Play("Jump");
    }
}
```

To learn more about animation and the animator this is a good start:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller?playlist=17099